# GWT : Method "getInnerHTML" is not applicable

Tags: gwt

Error at line:

```
  @UiField Label label;
  //.......
  String labelHTML = label.getElement().getInnerHTML();
```

Inspect Element Error while debugging:

```
  Method "getInnerHTML" with signature "()Ljava/lang/String;" is not applicable on this object.
```

StackTraceError:

```
  java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface com.google.gwt.user.client.Element, but class was expected
```

Value of `label.getElement()`, when I debugged:

```
  <div class="GEOL43OC- GEOL43ONY"></div>
```

Please help.

Comment: what is `label` here? Please provide some more info.

Comment: Sorry, it's `GWT Label`.

Comment: update a minimal testable code in the post.

Comment: Yup, found the solution [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/K-mr4bkjnfA). It occurs when you (try to) hotswap (i.e. change while debugging) code that is using the Element class.

Comment: @Braj thanks for your valuable time. :)